# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, connection-string

Iam using ms access as a database .mdb file

how to get the ms access drivers 2007 .

i got the error :**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

Comment: Make sure you're running as a 32-bit process, if I remember correctly, there are no Jet drivers for 64-bit.

Comment: @Aviad P - This is correct, there is no 64-bit Jet driver. However, OP doesn't say anything about Jet driver. Both x86 and x64 versions exist for the ACE driver.

Comment: Oops, I instinctively read Jet when in fact it says ACE :)

Comment: While there is no 64-bit JET driver, the 64-bit ACE is completely backward-compatible with Jet 4 and before.

Comment: 2007 contains no 14 see --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/

Answer (score 6):

Download and install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d) or MS Office 2010.
Make sure you select correct platform (x86 vs x64).

Comment: Most people have Office x86 on their Windows x64! If you have Office x86, also install the x86 database engine.

Comment: Can you please advise what version should I use for Office 2013?

Comment: for 2013 there is no Engine Package as the full Runtime, which also contains the Engines
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

and the provider goes to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0

Comment: booh, the provider stays at version 12... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32247214/1498669

Answer (score 1):

For OleDb connection and Office 2010, use "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" instead of "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0". There is no v14 as Office 14 has v12 for OleDB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got rid of this issue.Download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.That's all. Problem solved.

Link to download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255