# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: .net, excel, aceoledb

I'm trying to get data from an Excel file on a button click event. My connection string is:

```
 string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\source\\SiteCore65\\Individual-Data.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

When I click on the button, I got the following error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I have no clue how to fix this. My operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: If you're using 64-bit but still having problem even after installing AccessDatabaseEngine, see [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64), it solved the problem for me. i.e. You need to install [**this** AccessDatabaseEngine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)

Comment: Just a tangential comment: using OLEDB to read an Excel file is ancient tech, very slow, and as you've discovered, requires installing extra packages manually on your target machine. (Granted, the question was asked in 2011.) Rather use ClosedXml (available on NuGet) which works right out of the box.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Would have been nice, but ClosedXml only works for .xlsx files, not .xls

Comment: If you are importing into Sql Server you can run this query from ssms:


        execute master.dbo.xp_enum_oledb_providers


It will tell you what providers it thinks you have. It old me I had both Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, but when I tried to import data, I got the same 'not registered on your local machine' as the OP, for both Excel 16 and Excel 2007 file formats (oledb.16.0 and oledb.12.0 respectively). It makes sense to cut your losses and give up on the Microsoft software at this point.

Comment: Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401857/21579 for the difference between Microsoft.Jet.OleDb and Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.

Comment: @user1040323, `execute master.dbo.xp_enum_oledb_providers` tells you whats on the server not on your **Local Machine**.

Comment: [Here the one that should work;](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76/why-cant-32-and-64-bit-access-database-engine-aceoledb-dataproviders-coexist?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)  - It is : _Not really documented, but I did find a way to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Just add the command line argument "/passive" to the command:

"C:\directory path\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" /passive_

Answer (score 667, accepted):

Well, you need to install it. You're looking for:

- The [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: I downloaded these components and they did not work for me, I had to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255 I'm sure that's because I'm using MS Office 2013. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: I had to install the access database engine and the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 to get it to work.

Comment: My situation, everything was working fine, then all the sudden it started getting this error. SO what could have happened to cause this? No code changed.

Comment: In my case, I had to switch from "Any CPU" to x64 to match my architecture.

Comment: Jack the Ripper refers to the solution provided in the answer itself, not the comments. Installing the `2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components` resolved the issue immediately.

Comment: with regards to @RobSedgwick 's comment, I did still use "Any CPU" but unchecked "prefer 32-bit" option. Works fine.

Comment: Be aware that even on 64 bit machines, only the 32 bit driver works. I installed the 64 bit driver and it was still failing until I installed the 32 bit driver.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: Office 2016, SSMS 17.4 and AccessDatabaseEngine. everything is 2016 or the latest release and 64bit. I tried the 32bit version of the ADD, but it can't be installed. It doesn't allow to mix 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: I was facing this error while importing excel file into SQL server. This solution fixed the issue.

Comment: ِDownload And Install "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016" from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: This Link is now broken: I had to use https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Where is the 64-bit version?

Comment: This helped me second time, this time 64 bit version was not working , so I uninstalled it first and installed 32 bit version and worked !

Comment: I love how concise this answer is.
Gives reason and solution in two lines.

Answer (score 203):

A 64-bit version of the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable' that will allow you to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

If you use the download from the accepted answer, you will need to build for x86, as pointed out by @backtestbroker.com.

Comment: If using VS 2012, also be sure that "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox is unchecked in the project's Properties >> Build >> General configuration.

Comment: @post_erasmus - This step was THE KEY for me after installing the 64-bit DLL.  (May not have even needed to install.) Thanks!

Comment: I'm using VS 2008 (don't ask) and this solution didn't work until I read post_erasmus' tip and set 'Platform Target' to x64 in Properties >> Build >> General configuration of my application. Sorted, thanks!

Comment: The link in this answer also allows you to download and install a 32-bit version. Even though I have Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2013's IIS Express runs in 32-bit mode by default, and I already had some Office 2013 components installed in 32-bit, so the 32-bit installation is what I needed.

Comment: With this answer, I also have to set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" on the Application Pool to False.

Comment: VS 2017 with target AnyCPU and no Prefer 32-bit seems to choose x86.  It didn't work with the 64 and the installer wont install both versions so x86 for the win !

Comment: When I install this, Visual Studio 2017 still has the error in the question.

Comment: This helped resolved my problem. My VS 2019 app is compiled using Any CPU resulting in an x64 library. I had the 32-bit version of Office 2013 installed which prevented me from installing the x64 Access DB Engine. After installing the x64 version of Office I was then able to install the x64 engine and now everything works. DLL hell lives on.

Comment: So whoever receives my app is gonna have the hassle to find the correct Access runtime and install it? Is there some standalone substitue for Access database?

Answer (score 116):

depending on the app(32/64bit) using the connection you could just install

- [Access 2007 engines (only 32bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)
- [Access 2010 (32&64bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
- [Access 2013 full runtime (32&64bit ! >200mb)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358)
- [Access 2016 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040)
- [Access 2019 runtime](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-office-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9)

Summary:

- all offices from 2007-2016 contain the provider "Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0"
- depending on your application architecture choose the appropriate runtime engine (32/64)[6](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261)
- check your providers with the powershell-command **from both 32 and 64bit shell**:

  ```
  (New-Object system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator).GetElements() | select SOURCES_NAME, SOURCES_DESCRIPTION
  ```
- and you will see which provider your system can use

the long story:
the strings can be found with http://live.sysinternals.com/strings.exe

eg. on a 64bit System with 32bit drivers installed

```
strings.exe -u -n 10 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\MSO.DLL" | findstr "ACE.O"
strings.exe -u -n 10 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL" | findstr "ACE.O"
strings.exe -u -n 10 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL" | findstr "ACE.O"
```

even in the upcoming office 2016

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL
```

you will find the strings

- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB
- **Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0**

the Office 2013 comes also with csi.dll

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Csi.dll
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\Csi.dll
```

which contains the "**Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0**"

and Office 2016

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\Csi.dll
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\Csi.dll
```

which has the "**Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0**" version

Comment: I got this error in VS2015 using Nuget LinqToExcel. Turns out, because I had the x64 ACE installed, I had to explicitly build for x64 (Configuration Manager), instead of targeting Any CPU.

Comment: Powershell showed "Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0" was installed already. However installing the Access 2007 package (aka _2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components_) got me up and going. Already on my system: Office 2016 Ent, Visual Studio 2017 Ent

Comment: The PowerShell script that informs which version is installed is genius! Thank you @Bernhard

Comment: bit offtopic but this simple powershell is for your ODBC drivers : `Get-OdbcDriver | select Name,Platform`

Comment: This solved the problem for me on a 64-bit server machine by downloading the 32-BIT Access 2016 runtime. Basically start with 32-bit to be on the safe side (bad things happen when you try to switch things to 64 bit in the project).

Answer (score 63):

The first thing you need to check is your build configuration of your application.

- If you have **built your project under x86 platform**, then in order to
  resolve you issue you should install the following packages on your
  machine:

  1. In order to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider you must
     **install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**
     first, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255 .

     After the installation has complete, try running you application, if this
     solves the issue great, if not, continue to step 2.
  2. This next step is an unexplained workaround, which works for Office
     2010, even though it is the Data Connectivity Components of Office 2007.  I am not quite sure why this works, but it does and this has been proven to work in almost all cases. You need to **install the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components**, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 .

     After this installation is complete, try running your application, this should resolve the issue.
- If you are trying to run an **application built under x64 or AnyCPU
  platform**, I would recommend first validating that it runs as expected
  under the x86 platform.  In the event that it does not run under that
  x86 platform, perform the steps in the first part and validate that
  it runs as expected.

  I did read that the MS Access drivers including the OLEDB Database
  driver works only under the x86 platform and is incompatible under
  the x64 or AnyCPU platform.  But this appears to be untrue. I
  validated my application was running when building x86, then I
  installed the Access Database Engine using the passive flag.

  1. First download the file locally You can download the installation
     here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
  2. Installing using the command prompt with the '/passive' flag.   **In
     the command prompt run the following command:
     'AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive'**

  After these 2 steps I managed to run my application after building in
  x64 or AnyCPU build configuration.  This appeared to solve my issue.

Note: The order of the steps seems to make a difference, so please follow accordingly.

Comment: I had the problem that I was switching from a 32bit application to 64bit and it did not run anymore. The second part of your instructions works perfectly! The **/passive** flag allows installation even with a 32bit Microsoft Office.

Comment: Tip: Extract the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe to a folder to get the AceRedist.msi and a Data.cab files. Open cmd prompt in Admin mode and execute the `AceRedist.msi /passive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first option worked for me. I remember how much hassle I was facing to uninstall 32 bit Office & only after installing 64 bit office this issue was getting fixed earlier.  But this 64 bit office component done the magic instead.

Comment: Because of 2 point i have fixed. Thank you  very much. I need to install this one http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 .

Comment: We ran into this issue with an old app that we are supporting. This ended up being the right answer, but threw us for a curveball because we were installing the 64-bit version, since we are running 64-bit laptops. But switching to the 32-bit version of this fixed it (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe).. NOT AccessDatabaseEngine_64.exe despite the app being built for 32-bit and our OS running on 64-bit.

Answer (score 41):

I installed the MS drivers and it still didn't work for me.  Then I found [this blog post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mac) that solved the issue.  Read it there, else use these two images (linked from that post) as the TLDR sumamary:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was about to post this as my contribution. This was my problem. I'd change this IIS setting yesterday since one project in my solution was x86 compiled, so I'm assuming it will class the entire program as 32-bit.

Comment: My server is running @64bits but the MS Office Components installed is 32bits. This solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: What a incredible difficult thing to get working :(, I wonder if you could script this in powershell and just integrate it into some sort of automated server setup script?

Comment: @DavidRogers probably, but I'm not an expert in PS, so don't look to me for that! ;-)

Comment: @ShaulBehr Hopefully [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes/) provides insight to others, The specific command I used was(In a elevated powershell/cmd window): "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\./appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:YOURAPPPOOLNAMEHERE /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true"

Comment: @ShaulBehr, Thank you. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This saved me after quite a lot of trial and error. Thank you!

Comment: @ShaulBehr, Thank you. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Man, you saved my day, in my case this was the reason. I already had installed the access 2007 engine

Answer (score 36):

I got this error/exception in Visual Studio 2010 when I changed my build in the Configuration Manager dialog box from "x86" to "Any CPU".  This OLEDB database driver I understand only works in x86 and is not 64bit compatible.  Changing the build configuration back to x86 solved the problem for me.

Comment: The OLEDB is compatible with x64.  It can run under ANY platform, NOT ONLY x86, but as Any CPU as well. See full answer below: stackoverflow.com/a/32760211/3637582

Comment: Under debugging the application in Visual Studio it actually helps to choose x86 instead of any CPU/x64 in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 22):

Although many answers have been given, the problem I encountered was not yet mentioned.

- **My Scenario:** 64-Bit Application, Win10-64, Office 2007 32-Bit installed.
- Installation of the 32-Bit Installer    **AccessDatabaseEngine.exe** as downloaded from MS
  reports success, but is NOT installed, as    verified with the Powershell
  Script of one of the postings above here.
- Installation of the 64-Bit installer **AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe** reported a shocking error message:

[image]

The very simple solution has been found [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html) on an Autodesk site.
Just add the parameter /passive to the commandline string, like this:

> AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /passive

Installation successful, the OleDb driver worked.

The Excel files I am processing with OleDb are of xlsx type, produced with EPPlus 4.5 and modified with Excel 2007.

Comment: I could install AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe in usual ways but I used passive parameter to install 32 bit equilavent (AccessDataBaseEngine.exe). Then, I could finally connect to Access database from Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: This works for SQL Server Management Studio `v18.8`

Comment: This also works for SSIS packages importing Excel in VS 2019. Like @VolkanOzcan I also installed X64 without trouble but had to pass the passive parameter to AccessDatabaseEngine.exe (Must be the 32-bit version). I suspect that whatever one you install second is probably going to require the parameter.

Comment: Does not work for me, neither 32 nor 64 bit, neither with /passive nor without.

Answer (score 17):

For all those still affected by this.

I've been getting the error...

```
OLEDB error "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
```

...as described by the OP, Shailesh Sahu.

I have 64bit Windows 7.

My problem is within *PowerShell* scripts, but is using a connection string, similar to the OP's post, so hopefully my findings can be applied to C#, PowerShell and any other language relying on the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB" driver.

I followed instructions on this MS forum thread: http://goo.gl/h73RmI

I first tried installing the *64bit* version, then installing the *32bit* version of the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe from this page
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

But still no joy.

I then ran the code below in *PowerShell* (from SQL Panda's site http://goo.gl/A3Hu96)

```
(New-Object system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator).GetElements() | select SOURCES_NAME, SOURCES_DESCRIPTION
```

...which gave me this result (I've removed other data sources for brevity)...

```
SOURCES_NAME              SOURCES_DESCRIPTION                                                                       
------------              -------------------                                                                       
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0  Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
```

As you can see, I have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.**15**.0 (fifteen) not Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.**12**.0 (twelve)

So, I amended my connection string to 15 and it worked.

So, a quick PowerShell snippet to demonstrate how to soft-code the version...

```
$AceVersion = ((New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator).GetElements() | Where-Object { $_.SOURCES_NAME -like "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB*" } | Sort-Object SOURCES_NAME -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 SOURCES_NAME).SOURCES_NAME

$connString = "Provider=$AceVersion;Data Source=`"$filepath`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO`";"
```

*amended to pick the latest ACE version, if more than one*

Hopefully, anyone finding this can now check to see what OLEDB version is installed and use the appropriate version number.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to read Excel sheets with PowerShell. Excel files stored in a SharePoint document library and there is no Excel installation on the server. I have windows server 2008 R2. I installed Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components however when I run your query can not see Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB. Do you have an idea about that? and any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the answer. I had asked to our system administrator to install MS Access Database Engine. He had installed x86 version. When I run the query in PowerShell x86 again I saw ACE.OLEDB.

Comment: Awesome PowerShell code.  I had the 32-bit version (which didn't show up in the PowerShell list), which prevented me from installing the 64-bit one.  Once I removed the 32-bit version, I was able to install the 64-bit version without the "you already have 32-bit Office components..." message.  The 64-bit version did show up in the PowerShell list, and my app started working.

Answer (score 16):

You need to change the Solution Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" or "x64" based on the bitness of office installation.

The steps are given below:

1. Right click on the Solution File in Solution Explorer:
   [image]

   2. Click on the Configuration Manager.
   3. Click on the Active Platform Drop down, if x86 is already there then select that, else click on New.
      [image]
   4. Select x86 or x64 from the new platform dropdown:
      [image]

Compile and run your application.

Answer (score 8):

do this 2 steps:

1. in this menu: project -> yourproject properties... -> Build : uncheck "prefer 32-Bit"
2. in connectionString : write cuotes before and after Extended properties, like this: Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'

```cs
var fileName = string.Format("{0}", openFileDialog1.FileName);
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'", fileName);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, TableNmae);

DataTable data = ds.Tables[TableNmae];
dg1.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: Unchecking "Prefer 32-bit" seemed to work for me whilst having Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable installed.

Comment: unchecking "prefer 32-Bit" works for me. Thanks.

Comment: unchecking "prefer 32-Bit" works for me too.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by following the steps in this article: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

The key point for me was this:

When debugging with IIS,

> by default, Visual Studio uses the 32-bit version. You can change this
>   from within Visual Studio by going to Tools » Options » Projects And
>   Solutions » Web Projects » General, and choosing

"Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for websites and projects"

After checking that option, then setting the platform target of my project back to "Any CPU" (i had set it to x86 somewhere in the troubleshooting process), i was able to overcome the error.

Comment: Thank you, most other answers are for going down to 32 bit, but this helps you move forward to 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I am looking for .

Answer (score 7):

If you are debugging a web project, just make sure **IIS Express** is running either in 32 or 64 bits depending on your project settings.

Goto

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects

and from there check (or uncheck) the 'Use 64 bit version of IIS Express...'

Comment: Wow a lot of hours tryng other solutions, only your fix it! thanks

Answer (score 7):

A 64-bit version of the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable' that will allow you to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is available here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

If using VS 2012 or later, make sure that "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox is unchecked in the project's Properties => Build => General configuration
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If the installed "AccessDatabaseEngine" still does not help, below is solution:

You need to change the Active Solution Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86".

[OLEDB Provider is Not Registered on the Local Machine](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417397/OLEDB-Provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mach)

From CodeProject.com

Comment: You can run it under ANY platform, NOT ONLY 'x86', but as 'Any CPU' as 'x64' as well. See full answer below: stackoverflow.com/a/32760211/3637582

Answer (score 6):

First verify which version of microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 is installed in your system.

Check in below path C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL --64 bit is installed

Check in below path C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL --x86 bit is installed

If (x86) is installed then using configuration manager change solution platform to x86, for x64 change to x64.

If not available then install using below link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 5):

syp_dino,

The solution for me as you suggested for the **"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"** error is to change the Active Solution Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86".

When I performed those steps, rebuilt the solution, grabbed the EXE and placed in on the network, everything worked smoothly on the Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Comment: You can run it under any platform, NOT ONLY x86, but as Any CPU as well.  See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32760211/3637582

Answer (score 5):

I faced this same problem. Go to the Solution Properties and change Any CPU to x86, I think it will do the job.

Answer (score 5):

These configurations worked in January of 2020 on my new machine build:

(1 - x64 only) Windows 10 x64, Office 365 x64, AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 2016 installed with /passive argument, VStudio build settings set to x64 explicitly, with the following connection string: Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=D:...\MyDatabase.accdb

(2 - x64 or x32) Windows 10 x64, Office 365 x64, AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 2016 installed with /passive argument, PLUS AccessDatabaseEngine 2010 (32bit) installed with /passive argument, VStudio build settings set to AnyCPU, with the following connection string: Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=D:...\MyDatabase.accdb

(3 - x32 only) Windows 10 x64, Office 365 x32, AccessDatabaseEngine 2010 (32bit) installed with /passive argument, VStudio build settings set to x86, with the following connection string: Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:...\MyDatabase.accdb

FAILURE NOTES

Using the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 x64 provider in the connection string failed with only the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 2016 installed as above in (1).

Using AnyCPU in the visual studio build settings failed in (1). Setting x64 is required. Maybe this is because AnyCPU means that Vstudio must see an x32 ACE.OLEDB.nn.0 provider at compile time.

The ACE.OLEDB.12.0 2016 x32 /passive engine would NOT install when it saw x64 applications around. (The ACE.OLEDB.12.0 2010 x32 /passive installer worked.)

CONCLUSIONS

To use x64 build settings, you need to have the *2016* x64 database engine AND the *ACE.OLEDB.16.0* connection-string provider AND explicit x64 build settings to work with Office 365 in January of 2020. Using the /passive option makes installations easy. Credit to whoever posted that tip!

To use AnyCPU, I needed to have both the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 2010 x32 engine and the ACE.OLEDB.16.0 x64 engines installed. That way Vstudio could see both x32 and x64 engines at "AnyCPU" compile time. I could change the provider connection string to ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for x32 operation or to ACE.OLEDB.16.0 for x64 operation. Both worked fine.

To use x86 build settings, you need to have the *2010* x32 database engine AND the *ACE.OLEDB.12.0* connection-string provider AND explicit x86 build settings to work with Office 365 x32 in January of 2020.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar issue when we are reading Excel file.

History of the problem:

We recently migrated our application from 32-bit to 64-bit because of the memory requirement. For that we migrated our windows 7 from 32-bit to 64-bit. But still we installed 32-bit office on our machines.

because, of this we had this issue while importing Excel data into application.

Solution,

I downloaded 64-bit version of the http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and installed with argument as,

AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive

Without any code change my issue get resolved.

Note:

On 64-bit OS and 64-bit office, my functionality was working fine without this fix. This fix is only required while our application is 64-bit running on 64-bit OS which is having 32-bit office installed on it.

Comment: But, Microsoft is against this solution. Few of my clients observe distortion in other Office programs because of this fix.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when attempting to import data from an excel file (xlsx) into a SQL Server DB using SSMS 2014.

The [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) install did the trick for me.

Comment: ...and if that doesn't work, try picking a different "Excel Version" from the dropdown list of the "choose data source" screen.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56171883/283895

Comment: @Taran Link is not available

Comment: This looks like the file, but I can't confirm https://download.cnet.com/2007-Office-System-Driver-Data-Connectivity-Components/3000-10254_4-75452798.html

Comment: in 2022 Microsoft has deleted the file: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 ,
can any one has link to 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

Answer (score 3):

I received this error when importing data from an Excel file into MS-SQL.
The provider was already installed (64-bit) and this surprised me why it didn't work.
So all I did was locate the Import/Export application used here i.e. the .EXE.
And I found it at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe

I then ran the .exe directly to perform the data import. And it worked!

Comment: Hm, I had a few versions there, SSMS must be using the wrong one.

Comment: In my case it was located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn just find the location of DTS.

Answer (score 3):

**for Visual Studio 2022** (and newer)

I had this error every time and it didn't help anything. VS2019 was the solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/accessing-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#data-providers

> If you're using Visual Studio 2022 to connect to databases, you will
> need to be aware that Visual Studio 2022 is a 64-bit process. This
> means some of the data tools in Visual Studio will not be able to
> connect to OLEDB or ODBC databases using 32-bit data providers.
>
> If you need to maintain 32-bit applications that connect to OLEDB or
> ODBC databases, you will still be able to build and run the
> application with Visual Studio 2022. However, if you need to use any
> of the Visual Studio Data Tools such as Server Explorer, Data Source
> Wizard, or the DataSet Designer, you will need to use an earlier
> version of Visual Studio that is still a 32-bit process. The last
> version of Visual Studio that was a 32-bit process was Visual Studio
> 2019.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions set out by others; installing this patch, installing that patch as well as the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010.

My issue was that I'm using the same library (linq2sql) in 2 sites on my machine; 1 works and 1 doesn't.

Eventually I found that I had to "enable 32 bit applications" in the advanced settings of the apppool for my non-working site.

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Just download & install the following Access DB engine (X86 or X64: as per your machine configuration) and see the magic :)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error when trying to use ACE from an ASP.NET application, the most likely cause is that you have installed either one of the 32-bit versions. By default, IIS on a 64-bit operating system will run applications in a 64-bit worker process. 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs. When a call is made to the ACE provider, the 64 bit process will attempt to locate a 64-bit DLL. If it doesn't exist, you get the error message that brought you here.

In this case you have two options. First, you can install the 2010 64-bit version. If you have the 2007 32-bit version installed, you can simply install the 2010 64-bit version alongside it. If you have the 32-bit version of 2010 installed, you need to uninstall it and download and install the 64-bit 2010 version instead. You cannot have both the 32- and 64-bit versions of the 2010 provider installed at the same time. If you are performing the installation on your development machine, you may also be constrained by the bit-ness of any existing Office installations.

The second option is to change the application pool in IIS to enable 32-bit applications. If you are using the full version of IIS, you can use the management tool to do this (Control Panel » Administrative Tools » Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager).

For more understanding please refer below [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 1):

also can try these steps

In the SQL Server,
1.Open one data base
2.Clic in the option 'Server Obtect'
3.Clic in 'Linked Servers'
4.Clic in 'Providers'
5.Clic Rigth in 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' 
6.Uncheck all the options and close

Answer (score 1):

1.) Verify your connection string with [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).

2.) Make sure you have the correct database engine installed. These were the two database engines that helped me.

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)

3.) There could be an issue with your build target platform being "Any CPU", it may need to be "X86" (Properties, Build, Platform Target).

Comment: You can run it under ANY platform, NOT ONLY 'x86', but as 'Any CPU' as 'x64' as well. See full answer below: stackoverflow.com/a/32760211/3637582

Comment: Ok, well I don't think that was the case for me... so it's still worth mentioning that someone's build target platform may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in this case *microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider* was already installed on my machine and working fine for other application developed.

The difference between those application and the one with I had the problem was the Old Applications were running on "**Local IIS**" whereas the one with error was on "**IIS Express**(running from Visual Studio").
So what I did was-

> 1. Right Click on Project Name.
> 2. Go to Properties
> 3. Go to Web Tab on the right.
> 4. Under Servers select Local IIS and click on Create Virtual Directory button.
> 5. Run the application again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable** already installed on my machine but was still receiving the **Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider** error.

Then I recalled that I had upgraded to Office 2016 recently, so, may be I should try reinstalling **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**. And that fixed the problem on my machine.

So, if you have upgraded to different version of MS Office or even repaired/reinstalled your MS Office then try reinstalling **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable** before wasting time with finding other fixes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had tried uninstalling and then installing "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (English) several times and finally the comment - "Changed option from ANY CPU to x86" and it worked.

Thanks for that comment - I am now back in business after 2 weeks of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends with the office you have installed, if you have x64 bit office then you must compile the application as a x64 to allow it to run, so if you want it to run on x36 then you must install office x86 to accept, i tried all the solutions above but none worked until when i realised i had office x64bit and so i built the application as x64 and worked

Comment: Incorrect, I have Office installed and had to install the DB Connector regardless.

Comment: This solves my problem when NONE of the above works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to install **AccessDatabaseEngine** on server for web application.

Answer (score 0):

- I've been facing the same issue for days. I did installed OLEDB
  drivers for 64 bit, tried out 32 bit also which are available at
  microsoft website.
- I tried to reinstall office 64bit version also
  somehow it didn't work. Tried Allowing 32bit application in IIS pool
  true.
- Tried Changing project environment to X86, AnyMachine, Mixed.
  And almost tried all the patch that i could find on internet. But all
  solution disappointed me.
- Although i finally came to know that the
  provider which we were downloading was latest and was not working
  with it either.
- I uninstalled it and installed oledb drivers
  **14.0.7015.1000** .I dont have the link for it as i got it from company resources , you might have to google it but it works. 
  I came on this **[DOWNLOAD LINK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)** of microsoft and it worked too... however it is version **14.0.6119.5000** but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it on different computers:

I have a Windows 7 32bit machine with Visual Studio 2012 which did not have the Access Database because I do not have the Office 2010.  I copied the same source I had in my Windows 7 64bit machine.

So, I installed the AccessDatabaseEngine into this Windows 7 32 bit machine after downloading it per above suggestions from others here and everything worked fine.

I still had the problem on my Windows 7 64 bit machine which already has Office 2010 that already includes Access 2010.  The way I solved on this computer was by going into the PROJECT, selected Properties, and at Platform target had Any CPU I checked Prefer 32-bit.  Recompiled/Build and the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine message was gone.

Comment: Apparently, the Office I bought installs by default as for 32bit unless you buy Office for 64 bit machines,  I am not an expert on this but that is my guess - I will find out more if this is true.  If I am going to use it with 64 bit full potential then I have to download the AccessDatabaseEngine 64bit version as suggested by others above.  For now since what I had is the 32 bit engine I had to make my application prefer 32bit CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me right now.

1. Visit [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) then download that appropriated package for
   your computer (`AccessDatabaseEngine.exe` or
   `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`)
2. Install that.
3. Enjoy... Your codes are working now...

But for your application package you can use of any the following solutions:

4. Go in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared` or
   `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared` and put the
   `OFFICE14` directory in the same location of your package file.

Or

4. Attach two projects (in item1) to your installation package.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CsvReader from the Nuget package manager.
It is fast and easy and there is no headache of making any connections like this.
Just search with nuget package manager and import the library:-

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
```

Code:

```
var csvTable = new DataTable();   
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(new         
StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)), true))   
{   
   csvTable.Load(csvReader);   
   string Column1 = csvTable.Columns[0].ToString(); //Read columns    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't realize I had a typo in my connection string that actually mattered. Please note that the `.0` at the end of the provider is required:

So this is correct:

`PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;`

This is not correct:

`PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16;`

Answer (score -9):

//Read .xls  file

```
string strConnection = "";<br/>

string FileName = Server.MapPath("Student.xls");

strConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";<br/>

try
{
    OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
    conn1.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = conn1.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    Object sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"];
    dt.Clear();
    dt.Columns.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName.ToString() + "]", conn1);
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "0");
    da.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string ID = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        string Name = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        string City = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        string Marks = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
    }
    conn1.Close();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
//To Read xlsx file use following code
string strConnection = "";  <br/>
string FileName = Server.MapPath("Student.xlsx"); <br/>
strConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1};IMEX=1;'";<br/>

try
{
    OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
    conn1.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = conn1.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    Object sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"];
    dt.Clear();
    dt.Columns.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName.ToString() + "]", conn1);
    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "0");
    da.Fill(dt);
    //int idx=0;
    //int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string ID = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        string Name = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        string City = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        string Marks = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
    }

    conn1.Close();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

// Now install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe from  "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734" link

It will work 100%