# After installing driver still it shows Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ado

I install this driver.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255
Still It shows Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Answer (score 2):

Based on the link in your question you apparently installed the newer ACE database driver, so try using

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

instead.

Comment: What is difference between Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0?

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh RE: ACE vs. Jet - Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401729/difference-between-microsoft-jet-oledb-and-microsoft-ace-oledb).

Comment: :: I used Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 But still shows the same error

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh Verify that you installed the appropriate version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") for the "bitness" of your application. If your application is running as 64-bit then you'll need to have the 64-bit version of ACE installed. Similarly, if your application is running as 32-bit then you'll need the 32-bit version of ACE installed.