# Access Database format not recognized by ASP

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

I just downloaded the Office 365 trial so I can do my university assignment from home however when I opened my database in access 2013 and then re-uploaded it via FTP I am getting the following error message:

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'

Unrecognized database format 'D:\WEB\wwwroot\courses\benv\2410\2013s2\3420384\assign4\homerenovation.mdb'.

/courses/benv/2410/2013s2/3420384/assign4/post.asp, line 38
```

I was working in the 2002-2003 access format before this happened and I think it may have changed that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What don't you save your work in lower version even if you are working it on access 2013 database?

Answer (score 1):

Saved as a 2003 version and kept a a copy of the old one. The newly saved one is working.

Comment: You've got it working, that's good. Current versions of Access use the ACE driver. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401729/difference-between-microsoft-jet-oledb-and-microsoft-ace-oledb  and http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ for a bit more background info