# Excel VBA user defined type not defined-

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an excel program that can get data from sheet1 to sheet2 within the same file using VBA. But when I declared the ADODB, it does not appear in the drop down list. And when I try to run sub I get the 'user defined type not defined' error. Can anyone please share with me any fixes?

The code is as below:

```
Sub testsql()

'declare variable
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objMyRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset

Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

'open connection
objMyConn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & wbWorkBook & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
objMyConn.Open

'set and execute command
Set objMyCmd.activeconnection = objMyConn
objMyCmd.CommandText = "select top 10000 [Die No], Description from DieMaintenanceEntry"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adcmdtext


'open recordset
Set objMyRecordSet.Source = objMyCmd
objMyRecordSet.Open

'copy data to excel
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Display-Die Maintenance Summary").ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordSet)

End Sub
```

Comment: did you reference the Activex library?

Comment: how to? Complete beginner here so not sure.

Comment: Tools-> References -> Microsoft ActiveX Data object 2.0 library check the box click ok

Comment: @SivaprasathV Agree with you except that is should be `Microsoft Active X Data Objects x.x Library` where `x.x` depends on the version of Excel you are running.

Comment: You get that for office library like PowerPoint library.....you get ActiveX object library from 2.0 to 2.8 or something. I am not sure of the exact number

Comment: If you're just copying data from one sheet to another, inside the *same* Excel session, and you're not applying sorting or filtering, then all of this ADO business is probably overkill.

Comment: I totally agree with @ThunderFrame unless your are setting a complicated criteria search.

Comment: @SivaprasathV You should use the 6.x version (Windows Vista and later). 2.8 is for use with Windows XP and  2.0-2.7 are unsupported.

Comment: Thanks @ThunderFrame, I was usually going with 2.8 library without knowing the reason and thought that was the latest library. Since the code didnt have any version reference i thought he can go with the lowest version and thought that the later versions had backward compatability.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I will be implementing some complex filtering/sorting down the line of the program. But for now I need to make sure that the data can display first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Early Binding (as hinted by your code)
    What you need to do is reference the correct `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object`. For my version, it is `6.1`.

   [image: References Library]
2. Using Late Binding (No need to reference library)

   ```
   Dim objMyConn As Object '/* Declare object type variable */
   Dim objMyCmd As Object
   Dim objMyRecordset As Object

   '/* Set using create object */
   Set objMyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set objMyCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   Set objMyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   ```

As for which to use, I can only give suggestion. During development, use `Early Binding` for you to take advantage of `Intellisense`. At deployment, change to `Late Binding` to overcome version compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But now after changing the code I get a new error.

Comment: "objMyConn.Open" what needs to be changed?

Comment: @hjh93 That is already a new error and is out of scope on my answer :). Just kidding (but I'm serious), anyways, you need to check your connection string. Try replacing `wbWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: @L42, is the msjet4.0  dll available in windows 10 by default?

Comment: @SivaprasathV Is that related to this post or you're asking a different question. Btw, it should probably work (no way to check, I'm on Win7) but you should use [ACE OLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401729/difference-between-microsoft-jet-oledb-and-microsoft-ace-oledb) instead since it superceded JET.

Comment: I usuallly use Ace but for the CSV files ACE doesnt work, Whenever I use Jet its says jet4.0 not present. Is there awork around for this?

Comment: @SivaprasathV ACE works in CSV, but to help you more, post a question and provide specific issues there. Let us respect OP's thread.

Comment: Thanks,  I will do that, The Next Time I encounter a problem with the jet oledb