# .CSV to DataGridView Rows coming up blank in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, datagridview

Here is the CSV data I am trying to import into my VB.NET app:

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w1Xx.png)

But when I run it through the app it only populates the last row:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da44I.png)

Here's the code for the import:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    ofd.Filter = "(*csv)|*.csv"
    If ComboBox1.Text = "zVBImportTEST" Then
        If (ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            txtbxFilePath.Text = ofd.FileName
        End If
        Dim colsexpected As Integer = 6
        Dim thereader As New StreamReader(txtbxFilePath.Text, Encoding.ASCII)
        Dim sline As String = ""
        thereader.ReadLine()
        Do
            sline = thereader.ReadLine
            If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Dim words() As String = sline.Split(",")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
            For ix As Integer = 0 To 5
                DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(ix).Value = words(ix)
            Next

        Loop
        thereader.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a project.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out why the other rows are coming up blank. 
If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest trying to read the data via a StreamReader, instead use the OleDb class while passing the connection string for a CSV file.

Here is a quick example of a function that returns a DataTable based on the contents of the CSV file:

```
Private Function ConvertCSVToDataTable(ByVal path As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider={0};Data Source={1};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""", "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0", IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
            Using cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & IO.Path.GetFileName(path), con)
                Using da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                    con.Open()
                    da.Fill(dt)
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            If con IsNot Nothing AndAlso con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Using

    Return dt
End Function
```

Then here is how you'd bind your DataGridView:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.ConvertCSVToDataTable(ofd.FileName)
```

**Update**

Since you want to specify the data type of the DataColumn, declare a DataTable and assign it to the custom function, but then go in after the fact and change the data type of the specific columns. Here is a quick (free-typed and untested) example:

```
Dim csv As DataTable = Me.ConvertCSVToDataTable(ofd.FileName)
With csv.Columns
    .Items(0).DataType = GetType(Int32)
    .Items(1).DataType = GetType(Int32)
    .Items(4).DataType = GetType(Int32)
    .Items(5).DataType = GetType(Int32)
End With

DataGridView1.DataSource = csv
```

Comment: [Nowadays, you'd probably want to use `Ace` instead of `Jet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401729/difference-between-microsoft-jet-oledb-and-microsoft-ace-oledb)

Comment: @blaze_125 thank you for that, I learned something new today.

Comment: I like this solution. My only issue is that I need to specify the datatypes for each column, which is why I was putting it straight into the data grid rather than a datatable. The end goal is to insert the data in a SQL server. Is there anyway for me to do that with a datatable?

Comment: @AlanPear it looks like you'll know the data type of the column prior to loading it into the DataTable. If that is the case, then prior to binding the DataGridView, set the DataType property of the DataColumns. To demonstrate, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thanks but im still having some issue. For some reason all my rows are returning blank, but it's giving me the correct amount. Also, is there a way for me to include the first row as a header?

Comment: You specify if there is a header row in the connection string, in the extended properties > HDR. Here is a link on the specifics: https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Comment: @AlanPear, if you are going to use the Data Driver instead of manually reading through the file, you will likely want to use a [schema file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver) to define the connection properties. The linked documentation is specific to the JET driver, but its content DOES apply to the ACE driver. I was just never able to find the equivalent documentation for ACE specifically. Also, there is nothing wrong with using a StreamReader, for as long as your requirements don't fall outside the scope of what the StreamReader can do.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. One last thing. I got my original CSV file to import fine. It even matched datatypes on my SQL table without needing to specify type. Now when I try to do a different CSV file, it comes up completely blank. Any reason why it works perfectly for one CSV file but not at all for another?

Comment: @AlanPear, I'm not exactly sure why it wouldn't work. My suggestion would be to setup breakpoints and walk through it. It could be something as simple as the csv file not being formatted properly.

Comment: @AlanPear, in regards to your other files not coming in right, look at my updated code. the method `AddToGridByBindingTheWholeTable` should be able to handle any file. At least, it does on my end. I'm thinking you are probably manually setting the columns and there is a mismatch when comes time to parse a different file.

Answer (score 0):

This is C# but the snippet shows what you are currently doing, and how to do it so that it works.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridNoBinding_47308996
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.Columns.Add("Key","Key");
            dgv.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);

            Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdata.Add($"key{i}", $"value{i}");
            }

            //AddToGridNoWork(dgvdata);
            AddToGridDoesWork(dgvdata);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method does not work. This emulates what you are currently doing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dgvdata"></param>
        private void AddToGridNoWork(Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dgvdata)
            {
                dgv.Rows.Add();
                dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = item.Key;
                dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = item.Value;
                dgv.Refresh();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method does work.
        /// Add a new row to the Grid and store the new row index in rowindex
        /// Then use the variable rowindex to update the correct row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dgvdata"></param>
        private void AddToGridDoesWork(Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dgvdata)
            {
                int rowindex = dgv.Rows.Add();
                dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value = item.Key;
                dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = item.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your VB.net application, it's probably just a matter of doing somehting like this

```
dim newRowIndex as Integer
newRowIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
For ix As Integer = 0 To 5
    DataGridView1.Rows(newRowIndex).Cells(ix).Value = words(ix)
Next
```

**With DataDriver instead**
Here's my code, re spun using a data driver instead of the StreamReader

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace DataGridNoBinding_47308996
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);

            Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvdata.Add($"key{i}", $"value{i}");
            }

            //AddToGridNoWork(dgvdata);
            //AddToGridDoesWork(dgvdata);
            //AddToGridUsingDataDriver(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\DataGridNoBinding_47308996\SampleData.csv");
            AddToGridByBindingTheWholeTable(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\DataGridNoBinding_47308996\SampleData.csv");

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will do what you want using a Data Driver instead of a StreamReader
        /// Though, this method binds the whole DataTable to the DataGridView instead of manually creating 1 row per data row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataFilePath"></param>
        private void AddToGridByBindingTheWholeTable(string dataFilePath)
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            string connstring = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dataFilePath)};Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"select * from {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dataFilePath)}", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            dgv.DataSource = dt;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// This method will do what you want using a Data Driver instead of a StreamReader
        /// In this method, we are actively creating 1 DataGridRow for each DataRow in the DataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataFilePath"></param>
        private void AddToGridUsingDataDriver(string dataFilePath)
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.Columns.Add("Key", "Key");
            dgv.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");

            string connstring = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dataFilePath)};Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"select * from {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dataFilePath)}", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int newrowid = dgv.Rows.Add();
                    dgv.Rows[newrowid].Cells[0].Value = item.Field<string>(0);
                    dgv.Rows[newrowid].Cells[1].Value = item.Field<string>(1);
                }
            }
            dgv.Refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method does not work. This emulates what you are currently doing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dgvdata"></param>
        private void AddToGridNoWork(Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata)
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.Columns.Add("Key","Key");
            dgv.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dgvdata)
            {
                dgv.Rows.Add();
                dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = item.Key;
                dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = item.Value;
                dgv.Refresh();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method does work.
        /// Add a new row to the Grid and store the new row index in rowindex
        /// Then use the variable rowindex to update the correct row
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dgvdata"></param>
        private void AddToGridDoesWork(Dictionary<string, string> dgvdata)
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.Columns.Add("Key", "Key");
            dgv.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dgvdata)
            {
                int rowindex = dgv.Rows.Add();
                dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value = item.Key;
                dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = item.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```