# CSV to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I wonder what is my best option to parse CSV into a DataTable.

My CSV is in this format

Separator: comma 
Delimiter: double quotes (e.g."string")
Escape: 2x double quotes

**Here is the example:**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1234,active,"This is a long text with new lines, commas and all", XGF232
1235,active,"This is also a ""long"" text with new lines and all", XHD233
```

1. The problem is that numbers or short; one word strings are not enclosed within quotes.
2. The other problem is that long strings which are enclosed within quotes that also have a "string" nested are escaped with ""string"".

PS: Excel understands this format without an issue.

EDIT:

The comments pointed me at a different options. I searched the libraries available and I found LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv which seems to do the job just perfect.

```
Using csv As CsvReader = New CsvReader(New StreamReader(filename), True)
                Dim fieldCount = csv.FieldCount
                Dim headers() As String = csv.GetFieldHeaders()
                dt.Load(csv)
End Using
```

Comment: Use a library.  CsvHelper is pretty popular.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a document that conforms to the CSV rules a problem :) - what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: I was trying to use the loops with splitting, however this brought certain issues, which I think I could solve however this becomes too complicated and I believe there are better ways. Looking at CSVHelper right now.

Comment: A DataTable is not usually the final stop - if the destination is a DB, many will import directly

Comment: you could give oledb a go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp

Comment: You have several options. VB.NET specific, you could implement the TextFieldParser(1). A generic .NET solution, you could implement an OleDb solution(2). A 3rd party option, you could implement a library like @HansPassant suggested.

1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6(v=vs.110).aspx
2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310774/1920035

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. It pointed me at a different direction for looking up the answer. I found LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv which seems to do the job just perfect. More details above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV File Imports in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898/csv-file-imports-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Can you import from DGV to Excel?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\vb.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```