# Jet SQL, Order by. Order the column and respective data by keyword

Tags: sql, excel, jet, ms-jet-ace

I want to reorder a sheet in excel using an internal SQL query. I have 3 sections of data, say `A2:D10, A:11:D20, A21:D30.` and I want to order them such that `A21:D30` goes first in my spreadsheet. For each of these 3 sections column A is different like so, `Stack, Over, Flow` . So I would want to change the order to `flow, over, stack`

The logic would be like , but does not work for me.

```
Select * from [database$] Order By [Flow],[Over],[Stack]
```

I want to order Column A this way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MS Access, but I think you will either need 3 queries combined with `UNION ALL` or just change the column order of all sections to look the same.

Comment: [ACE is the newer engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401857/1422451) for 2007+ versions. Again, post more than your SQL snippet.