# How to change the password of a CDatabase object from afxdb.h using C++?

Tags: c++, ms-access, odbc, change-password, cdatabase

I can successfully open a password-protected mdb database using:

```
CDatabase::Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, lpszConnect, FALSE);
```

where `lpszConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=PathToDatabase;PWD=CurrentPassword"`

Now, I need to change that password to a new password. I've tried:

```
CDatabase::ExecuteSQL("ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD [NewPassword] [CurrentPassword]");
```

but this throws the following exception:
*Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.*

Is there a way to change an old password to a new password using this library (afxdb.h) or another similar library using C++?

**Edit:** my application supports 64Bit systems only, so I can't use the JET OLEDB driver.

Comment: Does access databases support this command? I know you can do similar with sql-server but never did that for access.

Comment: Basically. Although I would have to look up the syntax since I have used a different db engine for years.

Comment: Well, I know it supports `ALTER TABLE table-name ADD column-name INTEGER UNSIGNED` for example. I have that on another part of my code and it works just fine. So I though the `ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD` would work too, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Check here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab302426-ac1c-4a9c-81a3-38cf6feaec07/how-to-change-password-in-c-dao-jet-database?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @BankBuilder, unfortunately that doesn't help me since the [JET OLEDB driver is for 32-Bit systems only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401729/difference-between-microsoft-jet-oledb-and-microsoft-ace-oledb/14401857#14401857). My application is for 64-Bit only.