# Updating data in to a Excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to update some data in an Excel sheet of the format "xlsx" using OLEDB connection, but I am unable to make out the connection establishment.

Here is my code:

```
        String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" + "D:\abc1.xlsx" + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select * from Sheet1",con);
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;

        reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
        }
        con.Open();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When I run the code, I'm facing the following exception:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

Any idea how to recover from this exception or any other suggestions from which i can update my data in excel is advisable.

Comment: "when i run the code i am facing the following exception.. " So what is this exception?

Comment: What kind of exception? What's the message of the exception?

Comment: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: most likely the issue is with the bit-ness of your application. Try building for x86 and see if the application works.

Comment: You need to install it, have a look here 



[Microsft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider not registered on the local machine][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: yeap but no useful information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the provider you have stated try changing it to the one which matches the Excel version on your machine

Try

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='D:\abc1.xlsx';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

Instead

Could also be that excel isnt installed

Also check that you have referenced the OLEDB library for your project

Answer (score 0):

Change your `PlatformTarget` Type from `AnyCPU` to `X86`.

Steps:

Goto Project Properties.
Select `Build` tab.
Select `X86` from PlatformTarget options.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are multiple reasons for this exception.

1) You could use the OleDbEnumerator class to find out what providers are available.
Accordingly you set your connection string.

2) Before that just try out below connection string.
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + "D:\abc1.xlsx" + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";

3) If you have a 64 bit OS, there is no 64-bit version of the JET provider available and there's no alternative. As long as you want to support JET, you'll need to set the build target to x86.

Answer (score -2):

first save as your excel workbook as Excel 97-2003 Workbook
It will work in my project...

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ImportData/") + fileUpload.FileName;
 OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection
 (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";  
        Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");`


    oconn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Sheet1", oconn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adp.Fill(ds);
    oconn.Close();`
```