# "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Tags: c#, vb.net-2010

i have used 32 bit operating system and i don't have MS-office in my system and i used Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider in c# then i found error "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Microsoft Access database engine 2010` before you can use the `OLEDB 12.0 provider`.

See the following link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

**Note:** This is automatically installed when you install MS Access