# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" if Import (.xlsb) Excel binary format file

Tags: windows

In windows 7 I am trying to get data from an Excel binary format file on a button click event.
In errorlog.txt file shown this error message

**"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".**

Please suggest if someone have any idea to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the following tools depending on your environment (32bits vs 64bits) :
AccessDatabaseEngine.exe
AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable : 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

If you still have problems after that, you can try the following :
When developing a windows app : you need to set the Platform option to x86
When developing a web app : you need to enable 32-Bit Applications option in application pool.

Alternate link to download the tool : 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

For more details, you can see this thread :
['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)