# Import excel error after deploy application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

please need your help .

in my application i am using the file upload control to import excel file into database. when i am running the application in localhost it is working fine, but after deploying the application when i am running the application from same or other machine, the file upload control is not working and get the below error.

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Uploading code :

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
{

    string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + FileUpload.FileName)));
    FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
    OleDbConnection OleDbCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", OleDbCon);
    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);


    OleDbCon.Open();
    DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string con_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;

    SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con_str);
    bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[HP_temp]";
    bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
    OleDbCon.Close();

    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles((Server.MapPath("~/Temp/"))), File.Delete);
    Label_UploadMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    Label_UploadMsg.Text = "Imported sucess";

}
else
{
    Label_UploadMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    Label_UploadMsg.Text = "Error";
}
```

Comment: first always try to search on google

Comment: Please refer to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Sure , but i didn't find the answer

Comment: Dear Aliasgar Rajpiplawala, didn't work after installing AccessDatabaseEngine.exe it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Pay particular attention to the type of version (32/64 bit).

Reference: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mac