# how to Upload a excel file to sql database table using c# windows form application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, excel

I want to upload a excel file through windows form application in c# and want to import the data to database ( Mysql server). how can i do that??? I have created a form which requires me to upload a excel file into the mysql database . its an bulk insert data to database table.

My Excel File Contain columns like  userid,password,first_name,last_name,user_group    AND
MySql Database table(aster_users) Contain many columns like userid,password,first_name,last_name,user_group,queue,active,created_date,created_by,role ..

i need to upload that excel file to my database and other columns will get empty or null that's not a matter.

My Form design is 
[image]

Here is My c# Code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UploadFileToDatabase
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }

    String MyConString = "SERVER=******;" +
           "DATABASE=dbs;" +
           "UID=root;" +
           "PASSWORD=pwsd;" + "Convert Zero Datetime = True";
private void BtnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Text files | *.csv";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName;
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            txtfilepath.Text = fileName;
        }
      }

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)           
 {                
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtfileparth.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";

        using (OleDbConnection connection =
              new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                    ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

            connection.Open();

            using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                string sqlConnectionString = MyConString;

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[userid]", "userid");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("password", "password");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("first_name", "first_name");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("last_name", "last_name");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("user_group", "user_group");
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "aster_users";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    MessageBox.Show("Upload Successfull!");
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Here is how i tried.i got an error message like this

> Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

in this line  **connection.Open();** . How can this be Done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMPORT
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    String MyConString = "SERVER=******;" +
           "DATABASE=db;" +
           "UID=root;" +
           "PASSWORD=pws;";

private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
        openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xls";
        txtfilepath.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
    }
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string path = txtfilepath.Text;

        string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties = Excel 8.0";

        DataTable Data = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn =new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);

            conn.Close();
        }
        string ConnStr = MyConString;
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnStr))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE NAME";
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("userid", "userid");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("password", "password");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("first_name", "first_name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("last_name", "last_name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("user_group", "user_group");
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Data);
            MessageBox.Show("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
     }
 }
```

**An example found** http://technico.qnownow.com/bulk-copy-data-from-excel-to-destination-db-using-sql-bulk-copy/.
**And**
[ERROR: Additional information: External table is not in the expected format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287602/error-additional-information-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format/34288258?noredirect=1#comment56320429_34288258)

Answer (score 2):

There is an [**awesome link**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-data-from-Excel-file-to-Windows-Forms-DataGridView-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) that shows how to upload to c# datatable from excel...in case the link dies I am sharing the procedure....

The excel Connection Strings for diff versions:

```
private string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
private string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
```

The File select event:

```
private void BtnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Excel files | *.xls";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = dlg.FileName;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            string conStr, sheetName;

            conStr = string.Empty;
            switch (extension)
            {

                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath);
                    break;

                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 to later
                    conStr = string.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath);
                    break;
            }

            //Read Data from the Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            //Save the datatable to Database
            string sqlConnectionString = MyConString;
            if(dt != null)
            {                
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[userid]", "userid");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("password", "password");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("first_name", "first_name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("last_name", "last_name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("user_group", "user_group");
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "aster_users";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                MessageBox.Show("Upload Successfull!");
            }
            }
        }
}
```

Then you can just save the datatable to mySql database which I hope you know how to do...If you can't then comment I'll try my best to help you. Thank You

Hope this helps....

Comment: @ khaled4vokalz . Thank you for your answer.I tried this but i didn't get my output. here my problem is that when i click choose file button i get open my file dialogBox and select my file which contain data to import it in my Database table . The file path is shown in my textbox and when i click upload button the file need to upload on database.

Comment: yes sir please me please got an error like this Additional information: External table is not in the expected format. . still  i am searching for an answer.

Comment: @Arthi I have posted answer check it out.

Comment: Alhamdulillah....If that helped you then please mark that as an answer...
Thank You.... @Arthi

Answer (score 2):

ஆர்த்தி,

Use the Below Connection String Format

```
 string File = sResponsedExcelFilePath;

 string result = Path.GetFileName(sFilePath);    

 ExcelReaderConnString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + File +"\\"+ result + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: sorry for inconvenient . while running the program i got an error as (Additional information: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'C:\'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data) . sorry for trouble.

Comment: Please place the file in other drive except C:. Close the Excel file if its opening.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMPORT
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    String MyConString = "SERVER=******;" +
           "DATABASE=db;" +
           "UID=root;" +
           "PASSWORD=pws;";

private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
        openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xls";
        txtfilepath.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
    }
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string path = txtfilepath.Text;

        string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties = Excel 8.0";

        DataTable Data = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn =new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);

            conn.Close();
        }
        string ConnStr = MyConString;
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnStr))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE NAME";
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("userid", "userid");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("password", "password");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("first_name", "first_name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("last_name", "last_name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("user_group", "user_group");
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Data);
            MessageBox.Show("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had huge problems trying to use either/both Jet and ACE.OLEDB providers. You could try this o/s library ClosedXML, which will import xlsx files: ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine#comments-6649363)

Available via Nuget. It has its own wiki: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki