# ERROR: Additional information: External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

Need to import data from excel to Mysql. I am getting an error when fetching the **excel sheet** to **database table**.i got an error message like this

> external table is not in the expected format

in c# windows form application.So any one find where exactly the error.

This is what I am trying

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IMPORT
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    String MyConString = "SERVER=*******;" +
           "DATABASE=db;" +
           "UID=uid;" +
           "PASSWORD=pwd;" + "Convert Zero Datetime = True";

    private void ButtonFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
        openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xls";
        TextBox1.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
    }

    private void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + TextBox1.Text + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        xlConn.Open();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand selectCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", xlConn);

        OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbDataReader datare = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
        xlAdapter.Fill(data);
        DataSet xlDataset = new DataSet();
        string sqlConnectionString = MyConString;

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("id", "id");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("password", "password");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(datare);
            MessageBox.Show("Upload Successfull!");
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363480/4273349 Hope this helps you!.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the exception, make sure that you always close connections. In any case, the following might fix your issues:

```
String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    "Data Source=" + TextBox1.Text + ";" +
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString ))
{
    excel_con.Open();

    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Password",typeof(string)) });

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }
    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = MyConString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TableName";
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Password", "Password");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Upload Successfull!");
        }
    }
}
```

You have to make sure that the column names match and that you table name is correct as well.

This is based on an example found [here](http://technico.qnownow.com/bulk-copy-data-from-excel-to-destination-db-using-sql-bulk-copy/).

Comment: thank you JAMESBLOND. sir now got an error Additional information: There is no row at position 0. ...

Comment: string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); error in this line why they shows no row at 0 position??? please help me sir.

Comment: I've updated the sheetName logic a bit. Are you sure your excel sheet is called Sheet1?