# 'Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".'

Tags: sql-server

I M using `SQL Server 2012` and accessing other sql server's database in my SQL SERVER.But when I M trying to fetch data from `excel` it shows the following error-

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find
>   the object 'List of Blood Groups$'.  Make sure the object exists and
>   that you spell its name and the path name correctly.  If 'List of
>   Blood Groups$' is not a local object, check your network connection or
>   contact the server administrator.". Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line
>   1 Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"'

I have search on google but doesn't get any specific result,Plz help.

Comment: Please post your query statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)