# Import Excel File to Data Set in VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, import

I'm trying to import an Excel file into a DataSet in VB.  My code that I'm using for this looks like this:

```
Dim StrSql
Dim ExcelCon As New OleDbConnection
Dim ExcelAdp As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ExcelComm As OleDbCommand
Dim Col1 As DataColumn
Try
    ExcelCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" & _
        "Data Source = " & strpath & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;"""
    ExcelCon.Open()

    StrSql = "SELECT * From [$Sheet1$]"
    ExcelComm = New OleDbCommand(StrSql, ExcelCon)
    ExcelAdp = New OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelComm)
    objDT = New DataTable()
    ExcelAdp.Fill(objDT)

    Col1 = New DataColumn
    Col1.DefaultValue = 0
    Col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
    Col1.Caption = "Sr No."
    Col1.ColumnName = "SrNo"
    objDT.Columns.Add(Col1)
    Col1.SetOrdinal(1)

    ExcelCon.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    ExcelCon = Nothing
    ExcelAdp = Nothing
    ExcelComm = Nothing
End Try`
```

The error I am receiving says "Invalid connection string attribute".  Does anyone know how to fix this error?  I am using Excel 2010, if that helps.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Provider=SQLNCLI11;"  wont work with OleDB see [Excel connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)  Rather than `ExcelCon = Nothing` those should be closed and disposed

Comment: Now it says "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".  Any way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6649363/1070452