# C# to ms access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I got an shown in the below image on my connection between my ms access database and my c# windows form application,error says that

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLDB.12.0' is not registered to local machine"

visual studio2015 and ms access2016
i'm an amateur

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a lot of things.  Try [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb) and [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Answer (score 2):

Having recently dealt with this myself, I believe you need the **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

You have two options:

1. 32-bit version (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe)
2. 64-bit version (AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe)

You cannot install both at once. If you are targeting for the x86 platform, install the 32-bit version. If you are targeting for the x64 platform or AnyCPU, install the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you **installed office 2016 data connectivity components**? If not please install the same. You could get more details on the below links

[Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)