# Microsoft OLEDB 12.0 not registered on local machine

Tags: asp.net, excel, oledb, office365

I have created an ASP.net web application which reads data from excel sheet and displays it in jquery data table.

After taking a build and deploying it on IIS 8, it works fine on my machine. But once I deploy it on another machine which has **32 bit office installed**, there is **Microsoft.OLEDB 12.0 driver not registered error**.

But even after installing microsoft redistriuable and data connectivity components I am getting the same exception.

Every answer on stackoverflow covers driver installation but it dosen't help in my case.

Comment: Please make a better question, some code, reference what you have try - there are many answer for this issue on google...

Comment: also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: @Aristos there is no code apart from excel connection string...also can you please tell what you are not able to understand from the question ?

Comment: @Aristos I have already mentioned I have tried installing drivers mentioned in the link you have given..so your answer dosent help me.Thanks!

Comment: @Aristos further i have check whether there is 32bit oledb driver 
If 32bit is installed "ACEOLEDB.DLL" should exists here :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

Comment: @Aristos why did you marked question as duplicate ? There are other problems related to this question which was done after following this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/IIS-7-and-IIS-8-Enable-32-bit-Applications-in-Application-Pool-of-IIS-Server.aspx

Comment: There are people who might be looking for this solution so please remove duplicate mark

Comment: Your question is very bad formatted and very poor in information's. If you make a better question and show what you have try, more details about error etc... and the error message is the same... and a lot of answers in internet - show what you have try and fail, what is the different in you ? Even if the question opens again, you get no answer-help as it is.

Comment: @Aristos I think my question is extremely good and within few days i will try to add step by step things of what i have done to solve this issue.Other users might find answer to this question helpful.,.I will edit it and its not duplicate for sure

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/IIS-7-and-IIS-8-Enable-32-bit-Applications-in-Application-Pool-of-IIS-Server.aspx... This link is the solution for above question. for 32 bit applications on IIS we need to enable it explicitly.

Comment: @Aristos do you still think question needs to be edited.I tried my best to edit the question according to standards.

Comment: Ok I reopen it and see what is happends