# c# csc.exe, Access Database Connection Error With OleDB

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

i'm trying to use oledb connection, while using csc.exe compiler. But somehow code doesnt give error on .net ide, but gives error on csc.exe.

---

### Code:

```
using System;   
using System.Data.OleDb;

class vtBaglanti
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        string kaynak = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=okul.accdb";

        OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(kaynak);    
        baglanti.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("VT Bağlantısı Sağlanmıştır.");
    }
}
```

Error :

> İşlenmeyen Özel Durum: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   'Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12 .0' sağlayıcısı yerel makine kayıtlı değil.
>   konum:
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionSt
>   ring constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)    konum:
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    konum:
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnection
>   Options options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object
>   poolGroupProviderInfo, DbCo nnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningObject)    konum:
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection
>   (DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup,
>   DbConnectionOpt ions userOptions)    konum:
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnec
>   tion owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOpt ions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,
>   DbConnectionInternal& connection)    konum:
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInterna
>   l(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompl etionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   konum:
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnect
>   ion outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    konum:
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    konum: vtBaglanti.Main()

Comment: Use english in your visual studio  !

Answer (score 0):

the error means that The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. It has been discussed before. You need to install ACE components on your computer. You will need to match the CPU architecture of ACE to the CPU architecture of the version of MS Office you have installed.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32247214/5857386) has the list of ACE distributions for you to choose from.

The below 2010 version of ACE should be enough in most cases:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

PS. Welcome to StackOverflow, please check the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get started with asking, answering, voting for posts etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could't find old answers about this issue, so i'm new for this kinds of forums. Regards.