# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine - VB.NET - ACCESS 2016

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, oledbconnection, ms-access-2016

As part of a project, I've implemented an application in VB.Net that was connecting to a MS Access 2010 database to read/write data. It was working perfectly, but recently some people recived an upgrade to their Access application and they're now using "Access 2016 32-Bit" and now when they run the application it's throwing the error message "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered in the local machine".

- I went back to look if the driver was indeed in their machines and it is.
- The application was compiled using "ANY CPU", I change it to be x86 and it's still not working.

I've checked several threads regarding this same issue, difference conditions perhaps and I've read several solutions, mostly directed to 64-bit.

For example this thread: ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

I see several people install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components and it worked for them.

However I'm not sure if this will apply for Access 2016 or if it will mess up with the current installation users have on their computers.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide. If there's more info required let me know.

Comment: Based on similar case: [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874601), I think it also apply in Access 2016, or you can find a PC to test it before you apply any change

Comment: Please research all the links on the right under **Related**