# How to undo changes of framework change?

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection

Recently, I've been working on a project with Access database, but since the deployment would be on a XP computer, I tried changing the .NET Framework from `4.5.1` to `4`.

Since then the connection fails to open, and continues to fail even tough I changed it back to 4.5.1.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " + Localexe + @"/Database.accdb";
try
{
    con.Open();
}
catch (Exception x)
{

}
```

It says that:

> provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' could not be found on the local
>   machine

I tried opening a new project and seeing if there were any References that got lost on the process but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess you have to install Microsoft Access Database Engine? https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: You can see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32760211/3637582). Maybe you can fix it with this.

Comment: @tserdas I arealdy downloaded it, but it seems that since the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is only avaible to 64x, when I changed the framwork it lost some part of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OS and its bit? what is your access bit? x86 or x64? 
anyway pls try : 
**DefaultAppPool and Classic .NET AppPool** (find these path) - right click - 32bit app enable(true)...after this , right click and restart.
I guess it works.