# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider in import code asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

`The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.` on import code:

```
  if (flexcel.HasFile)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(flexcel.FileName);

                if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("../Content/MailMarketing/") + flexcel.FileName + month;

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {

                        // System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                    }
                    flexcel.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    Server.MapPath("~/Content/MailMarketing/" ) + flexcel.FileName + month + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    //connection String for xls file format.
                    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                        fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    //connection String for xlsx file format.
                    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        Server.MapPath("~/Content/MailMarketing/") + flexcel.FileName + month + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    excelConnection.Open();
```

How to solve??

I have already download this software but still not working..any suggestion??

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734
```

I have tried a lot code but the same issue..so any suggestion???

Comment: have you tried [installing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: yes................

Comment: any guess it is not working..?

Comment: sorry, I don't know. I just thought it looked similar to another problem with that error. But if you're sure it's installed then I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about only oledb..there is a lot of other method are used to upload .xlsx files(import).

Here is the header:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

Install `ClosedXML.Excel` dll from nuget.

Here is the code:

```
  string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/MailMarketing/") + Path.GetFileName(flexcel.PostedFile.FileName);
        flexcel.SaveAs(filePath);

        //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

            //Create a new DataTable.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add rows to DataTable.
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
```