# SSIS - Driver Error after upgrading to office 2013

Tags: ssis-2008

I'm running SSIS 2008 with .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on a Windows7 machine.

I upgrade from office 2007 to office 2013 and start getting the following driver error while importing from xlsx files: 
"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

I then install Microsoft Data Connectivity Components and now, the problem seems to be solved, but every time I run a data flow with excel source or destination I get a message box with the following:
"The setup controller has encountered a problem during install. Please review the log files for further information"

It's just a message, but the process stops and I need do click the "Ok" button so the dtsx continue running.

Any help on this would be great.

Many thanks

Comment: can we have the contents of the log file please?

Comment: I'm still looking for it but I just don't know where to find these log files.

Comment: This resource should point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: I follow the resource you mention and end up installing the 2010 version (Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable).
First time I’d installed “AccessDatabaseEngine.exe” from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734  (2007) and now, the same exe but from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 (2010).
With this I get the problem solved.
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem while working on .Net Application in which I am using Microsoft Access Database. Whenever I run application it encounter the same error "**Setup Error the setup controller has encountered a problem during install. Please review the log file**". I found solution in an [Article](http://article.itdk.net/viewarticleengcell/129147664801141) .
You just have to rename or delete following folders

- c:/program files/common files/microsoft shared/office 14/office
  setup controller
- c:/program files/common files/microsoft shared/office 12/office setup
  controller