# Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered while connecting to access database to my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web

I'm using **windows 64** and I got **Microsoft office 2016 64** bit and when i try to connect to the database I get the error:

**the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine**

I also tried to enable 32-bit application in the internet information services (ISS) Application's pool just in case, but that didn't work either.

Comment: question already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: i know i been searching for hours @IvoBarone but that didn't fix my probblem

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Access Database Engine for Office

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Answer (score 0):

did u try to change the solution platform as described [here]
(https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417397/OLEDB-Provider-is-Not-Registered-on-the-Local-Mach "codeproj")?