# c# trouble opening excel xlsx file in datatable

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I can easily open xls file with this code:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection theConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=C:\\Users\\us269229\\Desktop\\workbook.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\"");
theConnection.Open();
```

however, I cannot open xlsx files. With the above code I get the following error:

> External table is not in the expected format.

so I tried the following if the extension is xlsx:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection theConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\us269229\\Desktop\\workbook.xlsx;" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"");
```

theConnection.Open();

however, with this I get this error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

I did download and install AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe, but this did not clear my error.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Install "The 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components.".

Source:
['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: I did install it - I noted that in the above description.  It didn't help