# Auto Schedule report on PowerBI with Access data source

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm having an issue where I can refresh a PowerBI report from the desktop app however when I try to schedule the report or refresh within PowerBI itself I get the failure message that appears below.

```
"Microsoft Access: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine 2010 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider may be required to read 'Asda Sales Data.mdb'. To download the client software, visit the following site: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=285987."
```

Looking at the article below, I noticed that Access isn't one of the supported sources although it does state file as a suitable input. Therefore my question is, is it possible to schedule refresh a PowerBI report with an Access source?

"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-desktop-file-onedrive"

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/6649413#6649413

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)