# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.120' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio, ado, ms-access-2016

I try to connect Access2016 database(.accdb) to ASP.Net Gridview. When i try to connect, VS2017 showing error "'**Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**".

I also try to change configuration of website Active Solution platform. But VS2017 showing only "AnyCPU" option in that. I created Active Solutions x86 and x64 but non of them worked.

But i have MS Office 2016 64-Bit installed on Windows 10 64-Bit in my system. Existing solutions didn't resolved this issue. Any solution?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Yes i just installed that. By this the connection wizard connected database to gridview and shown data in connection test. But when executed in web browser showing same "Provider not registered error"...

Comment: Update your question to say exactly which database engine and platform you installed.- `2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components` is supposed to be the one that fixes a lot of 64 bit connectivity problems

Comment: I uninstalled Office 2016 and reinstalled and also installed  2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components again that resolved my issue. Thank to all who helped me in this.