# How to add Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in my .NET app installer?

Tags: c#, excel, installation, oledbconnection

I have an app that I programmed in C# with Visual Studio 2017 that use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to make querys and return some data.

Now that I published, for other PC's that doesn't have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 installed, the app returns some error and it doesn't execute the tasks correctly.

There is a way to include this Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in my installer, or other ways to correct this?

PS.: I have Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 installed in my machine to use the app with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 . I dont know if I have to install in other machines too, or how to do it with my installer.

I was searching about adding a reference or dll that solves the problem. But I didn't found anything yet.

Thanks for now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: @Plutonix Not a duplicate _at all_ - did you read the question?

Comment: What technology are you using for Installer?

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 publish tool.
"BUILD >> Publish"

I really don't have much experience in publishing an app. So I just used this.

Comment: I was searching about adding a reference or dll that solves the problem. But I didn't found anithing yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Create custom bootstrapper packages**

First, You should create a new folder named `AccessEngineDatabase`, then [download and copy the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) files you downloaded into the folder you created.

Next, Create a `product.xml` file as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Product 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" 
  ProductCode="Access.Database.Engine.2016" 
 > 
  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build --> 
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="true"> 
   <PackageFile Name="AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" HomeSite="https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" /> 
   <PackageFile Name="AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" HomeSite="https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/C/35C84C36-661A-44E6-9324-8786B8DBE231/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe" />
  </PackageFiles> 
  <RelatedProducts> 
   <DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0" />
  </RelatedProducts> 
  <InstallChecks> 
       <MsiProductCheck Property="IsInstalled"  
         Product="{90160000-00D1-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}"/> 
  </InstallChecks>
  <Commands> 
   <Command PackageFile="AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" 
      Arguments='/passive'> 
    <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed --> 
    <InstallConditions> 
     <!-- ByPass if the Processor is not x86 --> 
     <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel"/> 
   <!-- ByPass if we have installed --> 
     <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThan" Value="0" /> 
     <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges --> 
     <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/> 
     <!-- Block install on Win95 --> 
     <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="4.10" String="InvalidPlatformWin9x"/> 
     <!-- Block install on NT 4 or less --> 
     <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/> 
    </InstallConditions> 
    <ExitCodes> 
     <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/> 
     <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/> 
     <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/> 
     <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" /> 
    </ExitCodes> 
   </Command>
<Command PackageFile="AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" 
      Arguments='/passive'> 
    <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed --> 
    <InstallConditions> 
     <!-- ByPass if the Processor is not x64 --> 
     <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="AMD64"/> 
   <!-- ByPass if we have installed --> 
     <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThan" Value="0" /> 
     <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges --> 
     <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/> 
     <!-- Block install on Win95 --> 
     <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="4.10" String="InvalidPlatformWin9x"/> 
     <!-- Block install on NT 4 or less --> 
     <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.00" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT"/> 
    </InstallConditions> 
    <ExitCodes> 
     <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/> 
     <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/> 
     <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/> 
     <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" /> 
    </ExitCodes> 
   </Command>
  </Commands> 
 </Product>
```

You can easily find the product code in your registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

If you want to add a PublicKey to the PackageFile you can find your PublicKey as shown below.

Right-clicking on setup file, then select Properties

[image: find public key of setup]

Select Digital Signatures tab, then click the Details button.

[image: digital signature details]

Clicking the View Certificate button.

[image: view cert]

Select the Details tab, then you can see the public key.

Finally, create a new directory named en, then create a `package.xml` file as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
 <Package 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" 
  Name="DisplayName" 
  Culture="Culture"> 
  <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages and url's --> 
  <Strings> 
   <String Name="DisplayName">Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016</String> 
   <String Name="Culture">en</String> 
   <String Name="DotNetFxRequired">Installation of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 requires Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0. Contact your application vendor.</String> 
   <String Name="InvalidPlatformWin9x">Installation of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 is not supported on Windows 95. Contact your application vendor.</String> 
   <String Name="InvalidPlatformWinNT">Installation of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 is not supported on Windows NT 4.0. Contact your application vendor.</String> 
   <String Name="GeneralFailure">A fatal error occurred during the installation of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016.</String> 
   <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install this application. Please contact your administrator.</String>
  </Strings> 
 </Package>
```

Folder should look like this:
[image: folderview]

You need to Copy the original directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages` if you are using 64 bit windows or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages`

Right-clicking on your setup project, then select Properties.

[image: setup]

Clicking the Prerequisites button, then you can see your custom bootstrapper automatically added to the prerequisites dialogbox.

[image: prerequisites]

Select all prerequisites, then click OK button and rebuild your project.

SOURCE: https://foxlearn.com/articles/adding-custom-prerequisites-to-visual-studio-setup-project-468.html