# The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine even if it actually IS installed

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2015, oledb

I try to connect .accdb file as a data source to my Windows Form application in Visual Studio. It keep saying the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine.

[Error screenshot plus listed OleDb enumeratos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjUVE.png)

I have installed all the recommended runtimes on related Answers marked as Accepted/working:

- Microsoft Access database engine 2010 (x64)
- Microsoft Access database engine 2016 (x64)
- Microsoft Access Runtime 2010 (x64)
- Microsoft Access Runtime 2013 (x64)

but still the same issue.

Setting the x86/x64 platform in Windows Forms project did not help.

Setup:

- Microsoft Windows 10 64-bit Version 1809 build 17763.437
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Yes, I did, and installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 did not help and changing Target CPU in Project from AnyCPU to x86 and to x64 did not help.

Answer (score 17):

There really is strange mixture of platforms. I have installed all the necessary available within 64 bit and the connection resulted in "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine".

When I tried to install the 86 bit version, I got the "**You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed...**": 
[Setup Runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tSnB.png)

I followed the *Merav Kochavi's* advice to run the also the 32 bit version setup using /passive parameter ("**AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive**") and it went without the error message and now IT WORKS! [Test connection succeeded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bz2U.png)

Thank you all for help!

Comment: If you are using MS Office, which is 365 in my case, you will then get into infinite loop with version mismatch [screenshot](https://imgur.com/FWiSohb) - could not install 64-bit because of 32-bit installed > install 32-bit > could not install 32-bit because of 64-bit installed loop.

Comment: Help me a lot, Nobody told me about the same, everyone stated for installation of  `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider`, but that saves my life almost after 8 hrs, able to resolve the issue.Thanks

Comment: Installing with /passive worked for me, after the computer was upgraded to Office 365.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. Thanks for relaying the info.

Comment: thanks for your very valuable advice, "AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive" , now i am also ok, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone else, I was having the same issue. One Project would work, but not the other. I went to Add/Remove Programs, Uninstalled Microsoft Access database engine 2010. Then I reinstalled it with the MSI (NOT the 64 bit one). Here is the link to MSI:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Lastly, in VS, still make sure that you click Project,  Properties and check the box for Prefer 32-bit.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you check the `Prefer 32-bit` option, this problem is overcome if you have run the `Microsoft Access database engine` `20xx.exe` file to register the engine.