# Connection to Access database crashes using OLEDB provider (since Office 365 Build 12430.20184)

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, com, office365

An application crashes connecting to an Microsoft Access database when using the latest Office 365 build:
`E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF)`

**Environment:**

- Office 365 Version 2001 (Build 12430.20184) and later
- .NET 4.6
- OLEDB provider
- Access 2007 / 2010 databases

**.NET component**

```
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Sub TestOpenOLEDB(databasePath As String)
    Dim ConnectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={databasePath}"
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection()
    cn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    cn.Open()
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

**Exception on cn.Open():**

> E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF)
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>    owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) bei
>    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) bei System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) bei
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) bei
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()

**There are no crashes**

- when using direct DAO access
- when using ODBC driver instead the OLEDB provider
- after rolling back to an older Office 365 Build

Comment: See if this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756639/oledb-using-32bit-instead-of-64bit/55756667#55756667

Comment: @Mary Unfortunately, that doesn't help - application and office installation is already _x86 32-bit_.

Comment: Forgot to mention: A test application containing just the connection code crashes on the second attempt. The very first connection to the database works without problems.