# Getting 3706 provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed when app moved to windows 10

Tags: ms-access, connection-string

We have an existing VB.Net 2017 app that has been running for years on Windows 7. It's using an access database.

The system was updated to Windows 10 and access to 2019. If fails on both a 32 bit and 64 bit office of access 2016 and 2019.

Error
3706 Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

The app is 32 bit and must stay 32 bit.

Connection string first tried
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ATX QBFILES\xxxxxx.mdb;
which was working on Windows 7 then tried
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\ATX QBFILES\xxxxxx.mdb;

I am at a loss to understand exactly what it is missing.

Any ideas?

Thanks and Happy Holidays to all.

Comment: None of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6649363/62576) help you?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using the ACE connection string and instead used 
DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\folder\mydatabase.mdb
which worked with my 32bit app with a 64 bit access. It also worked on a test 64 bit app with a 32 access.

Don't understand why this has been so difficult.