# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine - Error with 32-bit office

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery, aceoledb

I'm getting crazy with this error:

[image]

There's a similar thread which I went trough but could not find solution for my case:
['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

I'm working with power query within Excel and connecting to a local Access database.

After above message I installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' 32-bit (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe) but then, when refreshing the query in Excel I get this further and worst error:

[image]

This is my excel version:

[image: r]

**Edit:** As suggested I installed Access Engine for 2016, but I get now this further error:

[image]

Comment: Try and install the 2016 version of the Access Database Engine instead, to have it match up with your Office version (be sure to remove the 2010 version first)

Comment: @ErikA your comment is fully reasonable. I did as you wrote and installed 2016 engine version. I now get further error as indicated in edited part of my question.

Comment: Are you sure that database is okay? Sounds like a corrupt database, that often generates nondescript errors when opening it with the OLEDB provider, but starts a recovery process when normally opening it

Comment: @ErikA I tried with a new access database and it works. But now I have a deep problem as I'm not able to repair the database in which I have a lot of data! I tried with compact&repair internal access tool but no lucky

Comment: Without specifics (and probably access to the file) I can't really help you on that. There are professional data recovery services for Access databases, though. If it's critical data, I'd try one of those, and of course for next time: it's absolutely vital to regularly backup Access databases, as they're prone to corruption, especially in multiuser/network drive environments. There's a reason people are able to make a living just recovering corrupt Access databases.