# Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 is not found during ASP.NET Excel .con() function call

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, vba, aceoledb

Currently, my web application can't upload an excel sheet to a SQL Server Database, because the error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

is thrown when an excel connection is attempted such as:

```
Line 40:         Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
Line 41:         cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
Line 42:         connExcel.Open()
```

I am lost as to why this error is thrown on my web application, because I am running a 64-Bit IIS Express 8.0 and have Microsoft Access Engine 64-bit installed on the computer. Am I wrong in my understanding that the 64-Bit IIS Express is looking for a 64-bit Microsoft ACE OLEDB?

Can someone help me understand what can cause this error to be thrown in this given scenario? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Share connection string...if you have just installed engine ..restart machine

Comment: There can be multiple reason for this refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'

Comment: This machine has already had access engine installed and rebooted prior to this error. Thanks for your interest in helping.