# How to resolve the ADODB connection string to updated window and excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I was using the below line for connection in my VBA application in window 8 and excel 2013 but when I tried to use my application from window 10 and Excel 2016, it fails to start with an Error.

**Connection String:** *Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source= " & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "; " & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";*

**Error Message:** *Error GetContact – 3706 – ADODB.Connection – Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.*

I am not sure whether window 10 is the issue or the excel version.

Comment: `Excel 8.0` needs to be updated I believe. Since you are now on  new Excel version.

Comment: I tried updating 8.0 to a different upward version, but no luck.

Comment: Does `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0` work? If not, does the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine) help.