# How to Add New Records to An Access Database from Visual Studio. (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

*Disclaimer: I'm very new into programming, so my coding skills are subpar at best.*

My goal is to have my Visual Studio 2019 project (*named Detailing Error Log*) add a new record row into my Microsoft Access Database table (*accdb file named Database1*, table named Data Collection) based on which checkboxes are checked. I would only like rows to be added, not deleted, whenever the "Import" button is clicked. The Database will then be saved and the checkboxes in my Visual Studio project unchecked. The Database will be used to store that data until it is used by a coordinating visual studio program to count the occurrences of specific text within a specific month. From there it will be displayed in graphs.

I had successfully accomplished this using Excel, however when the file became too large it caused a great deal of lag; both whenever I ran the debugger and also when refreshing the graphs. I understand there will most likely be a noticeable loading time, but I would like it to be minimized.

My problem is that I am getting this error at my con.Open():  "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0Data Source = S:\software\System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb' provider is not registered on the local machine."

What does this error mean? This is also currently the only error thrown.

Here is my code for reference, thanks in advance for the help!

*NEATOL = "No Entry At Time Of Log"

```
    Private Sub ConnectionPrep(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim dbProvider As String
        Dim dbSource As String
        Dim sql As String
        Dim inc As Integer
        Dim MaxRows As Integer
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        dbSource = "Data Source = S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb; Persist Security Info = False"
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InputInformation(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImporttBUT.Click
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder()
        Dim dsnewrow As DataRow
        dsnewrow = ds.Tables("Data Collection").NewRow()
        dsnewrow.Item("M/Y OF LOG") = Me.MonthList2021.SelectedItem
        dsnewrow.Item("TIME OF LOG") = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        dsnewrow.Item("USER") = UserName
        dsnewrow.Item("STOCK NUMBER") = Me.StockNumberTXTB.Text
        If MissedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED PART") = Me.MissedPartCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedPartCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED PART") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("NOT IN EPICOR") = Me.NotInEpicorCHKB.Text
        ElseIf NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("NOT IN EPICOR") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED BUYOUT") = Me.MissedBuyoutCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED BUYOUT") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If NonStockCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED NON STOCK ITEM") = Me.NonStockCHKB.Text
        ElseIf NonStockCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED NON STOCK ITEM") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED STOCK ITEM") = Me.MissedSTKItemCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED STOCK ITEM") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED AUTOMATED") = Me.MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED AUTOMATED") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY") = Me.MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD") = Me.MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If OtherCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("OTHER") = Me.OtherTXTB.Text
        ElseIf OtherCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("OTHER") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("ADDED MISSING DIMENSION") = Me.AddedMissingDimCHKB.Text
        ElseIf AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("ADDED MISSING DIMENSION") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = True Then
            dsnewrow.Item("FIXED DIMENSION") = Me.FixedDimensionCHKB.Text
        ElseIf FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = False Then
            dsnewrow.Item("FIXED DIMENSION") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        ds.Tables("Counting").Rows.Add(dsnewrow)
        da.Update(ds, "Counting")
        MsgBox("Entry succesfully added to database.")

        MissedPartCHKB.Checked = False

        MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = False

        NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = False

        NonStockCHKB.Checked = False

        MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = False

        MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = False

        MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = False

        MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = False

        AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = False

        FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = False

        OtherCHKB.Checked = False

        OtherTXTB.Text = ""
        
      End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have this provider "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" installed / registered on your local machine?

Comment: This answer deals with the missing provider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Thank you for your answer! I'll look through that post and get back to you on whether it solved my problem.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I installed the file that coordinated with my 64 bit version, but I still have the error. I went to look at my settings in the IIS Manager, but it rerouted me to a folder, instead of what looks like an interface. I may not have access to the IIS Manager. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd and 3rd answers in that link too. Seem to relate to build configuration and other changes for your environment.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Thank you very much for help, problem's solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might seem like a good idea to build your connection string that way but it's not. If you want to break it up then do so properly:

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder

builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
builder.DataSource = "S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb"
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = False

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
    '...
End Using
```

Doing it properly, you can't forget bits and pieces because there are no bits and pieces. You just supply the values. You also won't end up putting the `PersistSecurityInfo` value into a variable named `dbSource` when it's nothing to do with the data source. Pretending to separate your connection string components but not actually doing it properly is worse than not doing it at all.

You can also simplify the code above somewhat like so:

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder

With builder
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .DataSource = "S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb"
    .PersistSecurityInfo = False
End With
```

or, taking it a step further:

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
                                                      .DataSource = "S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb",
                                                      .PersistSecurityInfo = False}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this having the correct semicolons:

```
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source=S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
```

Source: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/

Comment: Goodness gracious, that worked. Really need to study a bit more on proper semicolon usage; thank you very much for the help!