# Import data (.xls file) into SQL Server - I get this error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019-express

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
> The operation could not be completed.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit version of the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable' that will allow you to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is available here:

[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255](http://%20http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

If you use the download from the accepted answer, you will need to build for x86, as pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions to avoid the installation of drivers. There are few options.

1. Save the excel file as CSV and then try to import it, using import export wizard. CSV is basically text file and you don't need specific drivers.
2. BCP IN the CSV file into the table.

```
bcp.exe {TableName} IN "{PathToCSVFile}" -c -T -t , -S {SQLServerName}
```