# "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." Exception is thrown while trying to run forms. eg purchases form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010, aceoledb

I've been trying to connect a Microsoft access database file to my Visual Basic application. When i try to run the application i get an error: "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" i am using microsoft visual basic 2012.

```
 Public Class purchases

    Private Sub Purchases_fileBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Purchases_fileBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Purchases_fileBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub purchases_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Purchases_fileTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TNJ_Retail_Management_SystemDataSet.Purchases_file)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Check link for screenshot of output. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20flj.png)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to correct the error simply by downloading Microsoft Access Database Engine and installing it in my PC. I then opened my project, rebuild it and run. Gave expected results. [Click here to open site to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe)