# I get the error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data) when I try to import an excel file

Tags: excel, ssms, oledb

I am using SSMS 18 and SQL Server 19.  I tried to find a download for OLEDB.12.0, could not, so I downloaded: accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe Which is 16.  Installed it, rebooted, still won't import excel.  Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks, Lou

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Answer (score 0):

AccessDatabaseEngine.exe version 10
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Ended up fixing this issue.  Strange, the error showed 12.0 was the problem, which is installed, I also installed 16.0, but it only works (import excel file to SQL) after installing 10.0

Comment: [Future folks](https://m.xkcd.com/979/): Most Likely me in 3 months...

This likely is due to application in question being mismatched with the drivers, between (x86) and X64. The AccessDatabaseEngine, some versions at least, comes in both flavors, the 2010 Redistributable being a notable example. There are direct links to both and the common page eliciting competing Solved and Not Solved comments throughout related SO posts.